# Azure Databricks rest api blocked by cors policy while making request through ReactJs web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, azure-databricks

Hi am trying to create the trigger button to my react web app. I am getting issue to handle cors policy.
I tried though the postman and It worked fine but i am having issue with reactjs. Also, I don't have any server as a proxy like nodejs to handle.
Is there any way we can handle cors within reactJs ?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState("");

  const handleClick = async () => {
    const url = "https:XXXXXXX";
    const jobId = "XXXXXXX"
    const token = "XXXXXXX";

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        job_id:jobId
      ),
    });

    const result = await response.json();
    setResponse(result);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Run Job</button>
      {response && <p>{response}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your code in my environment even .I got the same error when sent the post request , to run the job in databricks.

I added below configurations in spark config, even that did not work.
[image]

So, I can give you the alternative way to get this done is by creating a backend server which provide `GET` request with job id as the parameter at the endpoint `'/runjob'`
Then it sends `POST` request to databricks to trigger the job at the endpoint
`jobs/run-now/`.

Below are the steps,

First,
Add below code into your `react-app`.

```
import  React, { useState } from  "react";

function  App() {
    const [runId, setResponse] =
    useState("");
    const  handleClick = async () => {
    const  jobId = "679312719500343"
    const  url ="http://localhost:5000/runjob?id="+jobId;
    const  response = await  fetch(url, {
                        method:  "GET",
            headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":  "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":  "Content-Type",
        }
    });
const  result = await  response.json();
    setResponse(result.run_id);
    };
return (
<div  style={{paddingLeft:"500px"}}>
<button  onClick={handleClick}>Run Job</button>
{<p>runId =={runId}</p>}
</div>
);
}
export  default  App;
```

Next, create backed server.
Install the libraries express,axios and cors.

```
npm install express cors axios
```

Then add below code in the new file backend.js and
run following command to start the server.

```
node backend.js


const  express = require('express');
const  axios = require('axios');
const  cors = require('cors');
const  app = express();

app.use(cors({
origin:'*'
}));

const  port = 5000;
const token = "your token"
const  baseUrl = "xxxxx/api/2.0/"

app.get('/runjob', async  function(req, res) {
try {
    idx = req.url.match("=")['index'] + 1
    const  jobId = req.url.substring(idx)
    console.log(jobId)
    const  headers = {
    'Authorization':  `Bearer ${token}`,
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    };
const  requestBody = {
    job_id:  jobId,
};
const  response = await  axios.post(`${baseUrl}jobs/run-now/`, requestBody, { headers });
res.send(response.data);
} catch (error) {
res.status(500).send(`Error running job: ${error}`);
}
});
```

After the server started go to reactapp and click the `Run Job` button to get the result as below.

[image]

Here is the job triggered in cluster.
[image]

You can see run id's similar.

Comment: @SaiVamsi after following the above code i am getting error:
`GET http://localhost 5000/runjob? id=351513889530204 500 (Internal Server Error)`
`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'E',
"Error runn"... is not valid JSON`

Comment: Also I am getting following error as response:
`Error running job: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Comment: Make sure you are giving correct REST Api url,token and jobId. And to debug the error just print the error in catch block.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by updating `idx = req.url.match("=")['index'] + 1
    const  jobId = req.url.substring(idx)` to ` const jobId = req.url.match(/id=(.*)/)[1];` 

but i am not able to resolve `Error running job: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate` do you know how can we resolve this error ?

Comment: @Snooper_A, I tested in my environment its [working fine](https://i.imgur.com/DnLjrHy.png) . check your permission policy or you can try 
`http.globalAgent.options.rejectUnauthorized = false;` in your code.

Comment: where do i need to add `http.globalAgent.options.rejectUnauthorized = false` in my code ?

Comment: @Snooper_A In the front-end app inside `App` function. If still doesn't work, try executing this command `npm config set "strict-ssl" false -g` and run the app.